# Error "RPC context" running Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

When we run our google apps script, we get the following error message:
Error encountered: Tis RPC context has been used for a previous PPC invocation. Please create a new instance of the context to make a new RPC call.

What does this mean?
How can we create a new instance with GAS?
How can we prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please raise this in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), along with some either sharing your script or providing a pared down version that will reproduce the error? We should provide a more user-friendly error in this case, so you can know what action you need to take.

Comment: how to share the script only to the rigth people